# Which method is more effective: utilizing window.showSaveFilePicker or generating a data URL and downloading a file using an anchor element?

Tags: javascript, html, download

I was developing a feature that enables the user to download a PNG and a JSON. After conducting research, I utilized the window.showSaveFilePicker method to facilitate the download of the JSON file. For the PNG file, I generated a data URL and linked it to the href attribute of an anchor element. By triggering a click event, I successfully enabled the download of the PNG file. This approach was deemed more suitable for the PNG file as it originated from a canvas element, allowing for easy conversion using `canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG")`. Implementing both ways made me begin to consider whether one method is more effective than the other for downloading files.

The code for both downloads is provided below:

- JSON:

```
async function saveJSON() {
    const blob = new Blob([
        JSON.stringify({
            /* object here */
        }, null, 2)
    ], {
        type: "application/json"
    });

    const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({
        types: [{
            description: "Some description",
            accept: {
                "application/json": [ "application/json" ]
            },
        }],
        id: "save-json-file-picker",
        excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
    });

    const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();
    await writableStream.write(blob);
    await writableStream.close();
}
```

- PNG:

```
function savePNG() {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    // Logic to create the image in the canvas element goes here
    const url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    const a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'image.png';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Both approaches work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using `createWritable()` gets rid of Data URL creation, so File System Access API.

Using File API works on browsers other than Chromium-based browsers. For their own reasons Firefox doesn't implement WICG File System Access API.

Note, you can also create a `Blob` from `canvas` then create a Blob URL to avoid Data URL creation.